# Missing attributes after DXF import in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, dxf

I use "add vector layer" to import my dxf file in QGIS. But, when I open the attributes tables of the layers (point, polyligne, polygone), I see that the majority of the attributes (color, ...) of the layers has disappeared !!! Do you have any idea of this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This and others functionalities are coming...
(I think for 2.16)

http://blog.qgis.org/2015/12/08/crowd-funding-project-for-reading-cad-documents-in-qgis/

Comment: As of version 2.18.2, there is a new DXF / DWG interface. For the version 2.18. I recommend you the plugin "Another DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter"